# Proof about polynomials.

Tags: polynomials

I need to prove the following:

Suppose $f(X), g(X) \in \mathbb{F}$ and further that $f(X)g(X)=1$ prove that $f(X)=a$ for an $a \in \mathbb{F}-\{0\}$ i.e. that $f(X)$ is a non zero constant.

My thoughts:

Since $f(X)g(X)=1$ then $f(X),g(X) \neq 0$ also since $f(X)g(X)=1 \implies deg(f(X)g(X))=0$ and $deg(f(X)g(X))=deg(f(X))+deg(g(X))$ we have that $deg(f(X))=deg(g(X))=0$ and since in particular  $deg(f(X))=0$ then we must have that $f(X)$ contains no terms in $X$ i.e. $f(X)$ is a non zero constant as required.   $~\square$

Is this correct or no?

Comment: Looks good to me, except that f(X) and g(X) lie in F[x] :)

Comment: The degree property need not hold if the coefficient ring F has zero-divisors. Presumably you are assuming that F is a field (or domain). That should be explicitly stated.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit. Please don't overwrite a question with a new one since it invalidates comments, answers, etc. Instead, ask a new question.

Comment: @BillDubuque I looked at the question and the comments before your rollback, and the question was inadequate and the comments made no sense. Thanks for restoring order.

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly correct as long as $F$ is nice.